# Is it possible to programatically enable/ disable large text accessibility option?

Tags: android, mobile, accessibility

I'm working on a app that has a Settings screen and in that activity user has option to go to native settings accessibility options and switch on the large text feature. I would like  for the large text option to be disabled(if enabled) when the user logs out. Is this even possible?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking in to it, my understanding is that the non system apps don't have access to accessibility settings.